# HTML - How to put a header in the middle of an ordered list?

Tags: html, list, header

What I'm trying to do:

```
Header1:
1. xxx
2. xxx
3. xxx
4. xxx

Header2:
5. xxx
6. xxx
7. xxx
8. xxx
```

I know I could split the list and use the "start" attribute for the second part, but it won't validate HTML4.

Is there any solution that will validate?

Comment: The `start` attribute is valid in HTML 4.01, using the Transitional DTD. Even if it were not, what would it matter in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/M4hHH/4/

HTML:

```
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<ol id="list1">
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
</ol>
<h2>Header 2</h2>
<ol id="list2">
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
#list1, #list2{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
#list1 { counter-reset: item }
#list2 { counter-reset: item 4 }

#list1 > li:before, #list2 > li:before {
    content: counter(item) ". ";
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    counter-increment: item;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 2em;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `start`attribute is not valid in HTML4, just use HTML5 instead!

Using a single list, maybe you could hack it with css `::before` and `content`, but then your header wouldn't be (semantically) a header. And HTML is semantic, so if you have a header, it must be a header element, not just text styled as header.

**Edit**

Well, I have found a way to do it without losing semantics. If you want it, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17800730/1529630). But I think you should use HTML5 anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/r328N/)

```
<ol>

<h1>Header 1</h1>

    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>

<h2>Header 2</h2>

    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Yes but it doesn't validate.